# How to do string replacement in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I want to do string replacement in NSIS for following string: 
`C:/Program Files (86)` replaced into `C:/Program Files`.

I have searched and got this [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Replace_Sub_String_%28macro%29) for string replacement.

From that link i need to include whole functions. It may maximize the coding. Is there any built-in functions is there or any other way is possible?

Comment: You should not hard-code names and paths, use the NSIS constants listed in the helpfile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS only has 3 basic string instructions: `StrCpy`, `StrLen` and `StrCmp`. Everything else is built on top of that with macros and functions...

Transforming "Program Files (86)" to something else is not a good idea, the Program Files folder could have a different name (On my system it is called Applications)! Use `$ProgramFiles32` or `$ProgramFiles64` to get the directory you want...